# How to use streaming of YouTubePlayer when power button is pressed(that is,screen off)

Tags: android, background, streaming

I want to make an Android application which can listen to music through YouTubePlayer API.

People usually turn off the screen when they listen to music using their Android phone.
So, I want to make that.

That is, how to do Youtube video streaming when the power button is pressed (screen off) - what can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your application as service [read here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778)